# Symfony 4 - Manually Form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm creating my first project in Symfony framework.
I chose 4.0 version. I have a question about creating forms.

---

config/routes.yaml

```
home:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\HomeController::index
    methods: [GET]

login:
    path: /login
    controller: App\Controller\HomeController::login
    methods: [POST]

register:
    path: /register
    controller: App\Controller\HomeController::register
    methods: [POST]

timeline:
    path: /timeline
    controller: App\Controller\TimelineController::index
    methods: [GET]
```

---

src/Entity/User.php

```
// 

<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }
}
```

---

src/Controller/HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Entity\User;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig');
    }

    public function login(Request $request) {
        // ?????
    }

    public function register(Request $request) {
        $user = new User();
        // ?????
    }
}
```

---

templates/home/index.html.twig

```
...

<form action="{{ path('login') }}" id="signInForm" role="form"
      method="POST" class="visible">
                        <h2>Sign In</h2>
                        <hr class="colorgraph">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <span class="button-checkbox">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info active" data-color="info">
                                <i class="state-icon glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i>&nbsp;Remember Me</button>
                           <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" class="hidden">
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-link pull-right">Forgot Password?</a>
                        </span>
                        <hr class="colorgraph">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Sign In">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <a id="registerBtn" href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-toggle">To Register</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <form action="{{ path('register') }}" id="registerForm" role="form" method="POST">
                        <h2>
                            Please Sign Up
                            <small>It's free and always will be.</small>
                        </h2>
                        <hr class="colorgraph">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="display_name" id="display_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Display Name" tabindex="3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="5">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                        tabindex="6">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                                <span class="button-checkbox">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="info" tabindex="7">I Agree</button>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="t_and_c" id="t_and_c" class="hidden" value="1">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                                By clicking
                                <strong class="label label-primary">Register</strong>, you agree to the
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t_and_c_m">Terms and Conditions</a> set out by this site, including our Cookie Use.
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr class="colorgraph">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="7">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <a id="signInBtn" href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-toggle">To Sign In</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
...
```

What should be in the controller in the `login()` and `register()` methods?
I've read about creating forms in Symfony, but I want to use the form from a view **done manually**.

Should it look like this?

```
public function login(Request $request) {
        $email = $request->get('email');
        $password = $request->get('password');

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
        $user = $repository->findOneBy([
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password
        ]);

        if($user) {
            // TODO: Set session
            return $this->redirectToRoute('timeline');
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }

    public function register(Request $request) {
        $user = new User();

        $firstName = $request->get('first_name');
        $lastName = $request->get('last_name');
        $nickname = $request->get('display_name');
        $email = $request->get('email');
        $password = $request->get('password');
        $password2 = $request->get('password_confirmation');

        // VALIDATION

        return $this->render('message.html.twig', [
            'header' => 'Congratulations',
            'title' => 'Welcome <b>'. ucfirst($firstName) .' '. ucfirst($lastName) .'</b>!',
            'message' => 'The registration process completed correctly!
            An activation link has been sent to your e-mail address.',
            'button' => [
                'href' => $this->generateUrl('home'),
                'text' => 'To Sign In'
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: No password hash? No salt? If you're new to Symfony, start using FosUserBundle. You're trying to reinvent the wheel and what you've got right now is something square. Please read https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html.

Comment: @StephanVierkant, I like to reinvent the wheel :D Thanks!

Comment: Whatever you do stay far far far away from FOSUserBundle especially as a new Symfony developer.  Instead, consider consulting the Symfony docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Comment: Please, don't do thinks manually, just because you want it. Components like Security, Forms, etc. are there for a reason. If you're new to Symfony, it's sometimes hard to figure out how something should work. But remember making a mess of your application by reinventing the wheel is a lot easier (on short term). If you want to learn; how to configure the components. Create a custom Twig template, extend the User class, use the event system, etc. Symfony is configurable and extendable.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with @Cerad, but I can imagine why he is saying it. Read the documentation (we already provided two links, but there is a hell of a lot more on Symfony.com) and choose for yourself. Whatever you do, start reading https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html. In it's current form, this question is too broad and should be closed IMHO.

Comment: Okay, thanks to you. You are really good people.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented a small and simple login & reset password actions without fosuserbundle in Symfony 4. This is not so complicated to do:

Configure your security:

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        our_db_provider: # Arbitrary name
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            provider: our_db_provider # Use any declared provider above
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                default_target_path: /
            anonymous: true
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

The login action:

```
// src/Controller/Security/SecurityController.php
namespace App\Controller\Security;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
    {
        $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('Security/login.html.twig', [
            'error' => $error,
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The login template

```
# templates/Security/login.html.twig
{% block body %}
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <div class="login-page">
        <div class="form">

            {% if error %}
                <div class="error">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
            {% endif %}

            <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">

                <div>
                    <label for="username">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
                </div>
                <div class="cta">
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" checked />
                        <label for="remember_me">Keep me logged in</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit">Connexion</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="{{ path('request_password') }}">Forgot password ?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The User Manager:

```
# src/Manager/UserManager.php
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Util\PasswordUpdater;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * Class UserManager
 * @package App\Manager
 */
class UserManager
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface  */
    private $em;

    /** @var PasswordUpdater  */
    private $passwordUpdater;

    /**
     * UserManager constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     * @param PasswordUpdater $passwordUpdater
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, PasswordUpdater $passwordUpdater)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->passwordUpdater = $passwordUpdater;
    }

    /**
     * Find a user by his username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\User|null
     */
    public function findUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\User')->findOneBy(['username' => $username]);

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Update a user
     *
     * @param AdvancedUserInterface $user
     *
     * @param bool $andFlush
     */
    public function updateUser(AdvancedUserInterface $user, $andFlush = true)
    {
        $this->em->persist($user);

        if ($andFlush) {
            $this->em->flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find a user by his confirmationToken
     *
     * @param $confirmationToken
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\User|null
     */
    public function findUserByConfirmationToken($confirmationToken)
    {
        $user = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\User')->findOneBy(['confirmationToken' => $confirmationToken]);

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Encode & update user password
     *
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function updateUserPassword(User $user)
    {
        $this->passwordUpdater->hashPassword($user);
        $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
        $user->setPasswordRequestedAt(null);
    }
}
```

And the User Entity:

```
# src/Entity/User.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * Random string sent to the user email address in order to verify it.
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $confirmationToken;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $passwordRequestedAt;

    /**
     * User constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->username = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function isActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $isActive
     * @return User
     */
    public function setActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getConfirmationToken()
    {
        return $this->confirmationToken;
    }

    /**
     * @param $confirmationToken
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setConfirmationToken($confirmationToken)
    {
        $this->confirmationToken = $confirmationToken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime|null $date
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPasswordRequestedAt(\DateTime $date = null)
    {
        $this->passwordRequestedAt = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the timestamp that the user requested a password reset.
     *
     * @return null|\DateTime
     */
    public function getPasswordRequestedAt()
    {
        return $this->passwordRequestedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param $ttl
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isPasswordRequestNonExpired($ttl)
    {
        return $this->getPasswordRequestedAt() instanceof \DateTime &&
            $this->getPasswordRequestedAt()->getTimestamp() + $ttl > time();
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

This is the way I deal with it. This is problably not perfect, but it works fine. You can find sources here : https://github.com/matthieuleorat/documentManager

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Just for info, storing the password (even if it is encoded) in the session is not necessary and generally frowned upon.  Out of the box the user will be reloaded on each request.  The password is not checked on each request.  In fact, you really don't need anything beyond the id.

Comment: Hello @Cerad, thank you for your comment. The authentification wasn't working without the isActive in the serialization method.

Comment: Seems a bit strange that isActive would be checked before the user is refreshed from the database but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: Maybe i missconfigured something else, I don't know

Answer (score -1):

the login controller must to be something like this:

```
 /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login_route")
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {

        $autenticacion = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // if there is any error, here you get it
        $error = $autenticacion->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $autenticacion->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render(
            'login.html.twig',
            array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error' => $error,
            )
        );
    }
```

And the register do it saving the input in the view, you can use Type, becase the form needs hidden inputs for security.

Comment: I downvoted this answer for multiple reasons. This will not work, it tries to answer just one part of the question and it assumes Symfony Form Component being used.

Comment: Then use Symfony Form Component.

Comment: Read the question (including comments): " I want to use the form from a view done manually.")